# Autowired spring bean is nul

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, elasticsearch

I have a simple class defined that holds configuration properties for my elasticsearch client (called ElasticClientConfig.java).

I have a configuration defined for my development, prod, and test environments. Each configuration profile has a method that returns a bean of type ElasticClientConfig, and builds a MyConfig object with the parameters specific to the environment. Here is the version for development:

```
@Configuration
@Profile("dev")
public class DevConfig {

    @Bean
    public ElasticClientConfig getElasticClientConfig(){
          //build the ElasticSearchConfig and return it
    }

}
```

I set my active profile as 'dev' in my web.xml file:

```
   <context-param>
      <param-name>spring.profiles.active</param-name>
      <param-value>dev</param-value>
   </context-param>
```

I inject a ElasticClientConfig object using the @Autowired annotation, but it is null. Any ideas on what I can check? My spring-servlet.xml file is very simple:

```
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
    xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
    xmlns:mvc="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-4.0.xsd
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc/spring-mvc-4.0.xsd
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/context http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-4.0.xsd">

    <context:component-scan base-package="com.elasticapp" />

    <mvc:annotation-driven />

    <bean
        class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver">
        <property name="prefix">
            <value>/WEB-INF/views/</value>
        </property>
        <property name="suffix">
            <value>.jsp</value>
        </property>
    </bean>
    <bean class="com.elasticapp.client.ElasticClient"/>
</beans>
```

The ElasticClient is the class that I am injecting the ElasticClientConfig into.

Answer (score 0):

I forgot about how dependency injection works, realized I was trying to access an autowired property in the constructor. Decided to use @PostConstruct, works perfectly!